# Why is the answer about 'relative import path "$fresh/dev.ts" not prefixed' deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Answer in question: [Deno - Relative import path "$fresh/dev.ts" not prefixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77890469/3416774)

Its first version was:

> In my case, I want to [change the source directory](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/examples/changing-the-src-dir). If the path contains a space or a non-ASCII character then it will yield this error. I haven't figured out how to escape those characters.

After receiving some feedback that it doesn't look like an answer, I changed it to:

> Make sure the path does not contain a space or a non-ASCII character, especially when you [change the source directory](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/examples/changing-the-src-dir). I haven't figured out how to escape those characters.
>
> [I've made the issue in denoland/deploy_feedback](https://github.com/denoland/deploy_feedback/issues/590#event-11481105065).

Why is this still not an answer? And isn't there a reason for the deletion? Something like the close reason for closed questions.

Comment: "I haven't figured out how to escape those characters." and "I've made the issue in denoland/deploy_feedback." reads very much like the post is about announcing your issue - i.e. a question about it. While the first sentence can go either way (the edit improved it substantially) it doesn’t seem to match the question.

Comment: what you mean by not matching? That I give the wrong answer for the question?

Comment: the paths in the question already "does not contain a space or a non-ASCII character" so it’s frankly unclear to me what the advice is supposed to address in the first place. It might be an answer to a similar question (e.g. the same error in a different situation) but it might just as well not.

Comment: I mean one of the reason is because there is a space or a non-ASCII character in your path. Eliminate that reason does not mean there is no more reason. The OP doesn't need to care that, but other people coming to the question may need to keep that in mind

Comment: I recommend to rewrite your answer as such.

Comment: Done. Is there any reason that it should be deleted?

Comment: FYI, I retracted my vote after you edited the answer. https://i.imgur.com/uI62I5B.png

Comment: @Cow thanks. I wonder why you still decide to vote it as not an answer, given our conversation over there? What isn't convincing to you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A moderator deleted the answer in response to multiple Not An Answer flags. In the original version, the answer was very short, and the text read quite a bit like it was describing your own problem, rather than presenting a solution to the question, particularly given that the question didn't exhibit the issue which the answer is saying to avoid. At the time of deletion, the answer had been improved significantly to the point where I'm not sure why it was evaluated as not an answer and deleted.

You've edited the answer such that it's clearer that the answer is giving a solution to an alternate cause of the error in the question, rather than about resolving the issue that's specifically in the fuller detail in the question. The fuller detail in the question relies on an image, rather than text, to provide the information needed to know that the error isn't caused by the reason you're resolving. While that's not ideal for an answer, it is, in my opinion, sufficiently beyond what we consider as "Not An Answer", such that it shouldn't be deleted by a moderator as not an answer (i.e. the answer is potentially useful to future visitors). I've, thus, undeleted the answer.

Comment: why doesn't the deletion notice explain the deletion reason? In close notice there is always a reason

Comment: @Ooker Because the system doesn't work that way. For deletions, the system doesn't have a method to specify a reason, it's just "delete". Thus, no specific reason can be shown in the post notice. While there are some circumstances where the system showing a deletion reason might be useful, the vast majority of those could be handled with a comment, if the user voting for deletion chooses to post one. There are some deletion reasons which are shown for answers, but those are fairly limited. IIRC, it's: spam, rude/abusive, plagiarism, and when the answer is deleted along with the question.

Comment: Why wouldn't the system allow the deletors to select the reason?

Comment: Because the system **has no concept** of the idea that there is a reason for deletions.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I mean, why wouldn't the designers have such a concept of the reasons for deletions?

Comment: Because they saw no reason to keep track of it... ?